# request clarification of transposition example in McBride/Paterson Applicative paper

Tags: haskell, monads

Conor McBride's and Ross Paterson's classic paper
[Applicative programming with effects](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.pdf)
shows a 'matrice' transposition example:

```
transpose   :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose [] = repeat []
transpose (xs : xss) = zipWith (:) xs (transpose xss)
```

`transpose` is using the "collection point of view" of lists: it pairs
functions (here `(:)`) and inputs elementwise and produce list of resulting
outputs.

Therefore, given

```
v = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

then

```
transpose  v
```

results in

```
[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

Later in the paper they say

If we want to do the same for our transpose example, we shall have to
avoid the library’s 'list of successes' (Wadler, 1985) monad and take
instead an instance `Applicative []` that supports 'vectorization',
where `pure = repeat` and `(~) = zapp`, yielding

```
transpose'' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose''         [] = pure []
transpose'' (xs : xss) = pure (:) <*> xs <*> transpose'' xss
```

Here, `transpose''` is using the "non-deterministic computation point
of view" of lists: it applies the function (here `(:)`) to inputs in
turn.

Therefore

```
 transpose'' v
```

results in

```
 [[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],[2,4],[2,5],[2,6],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6]]
```

I feel I am missing some subtle point.  I can see that `transpose` is
indeed transposing a "vector" using the collection point of view of
lists.  But `transpose''` (using the non-deterministic computation
point of view of lists) seems to have nothing to do with vector
transposition.

In other words, `transpose` and `transpose''` seem to be unrelated
functions - different examples.  Am I missing something?

Comment: The comment "we shall have to avoid the library's 'list of successes'" is exactly saying that we are *not* using the "non-deterministic computation point of view".

Comment: Note that there's a `newtype ZipList` in `Control.Applicative` that has exactly the shown behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where `pure = repeat` and `(❄) = zapp`, yielding...

This is *not* the standard list instance. To implement this in Haskell, we need

```
newtype Zapp a = Zapp { runZapp : [a] } deriving (Functor)
zcons :: a -> Zapp a -> Zapp a
zcons x (Zapp xs) = Zapp $ x : xs

instance Applicative Zapp where
  pure = Zapp . repeat
  Zapp a <*> Zapp b = Zapp $ zapp a b
```

and then

```
transpose'' :: Zapp (Zapp a) -> Zapp (Zapp a)
transpose''         (Zapp []) = pure $ Zapp []
transpose'' (Zapp (xs : xss)) = pure zcons <*> xs <*> transpose'' xss
```

Comment: Ouch!  I need to read more closely - as you point out, why I was unclear is because I missed `pure = repeat` ...    - thanks!

Comment: In my defense, the paper is using the idiom brackets at this one point to mean something different than the rest of the paper.  Still, I was blindly translating ...

Answer (score 1):

If you make the instance listed for the first example, where the `Applicative` instance has `pure = repeat` and `<*> = zapp`

```
instance Applicative [] where
    pure = repeat
    (<*>) = zapp

transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose         [] = pure []
transpose (xs : xss) = pure (:) <*> xs <*> transpose xss

main = do
    print . transpose $ [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

You get the transposition from transpose:

```
[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

If, instead, you use the normal `Applicative` instance for `[]`

```
instance Applicative [] where
    pure x = [x]
    fs <*> xs = [f x | f <- fs, x <- xs]

transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose         [] = pure []
transpose (xs : xss) = pure (:) <*> xs <*> transpose xss

main = do
    print . transpose $ [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

You get

```
[[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],[2,4],[2,5],[2,6],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6]]
```

The boilerplate for both of those examples is:

```
module Main (
    main
) where

import Prelude hiding (repeat)

infixl 4 <*>
class Applicative f where
    pure :: a -> f a
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

repeat :: a -> [a]
repeat x = x : repeat x

zapp :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]
zapp (f : fs) (x : xs) = f x : zapp fs xs
zapp _        _        = []
```